# valign="top" not working in td

Tags: html, css

I have images in my td. I have to align them top, but these are displaying in middle. I am using following html.

```
<table> 
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">                       
            <img src="./images/facebook.jpg" name="facebook" border=0 width=40 height=40>
            <img src="./images/twitter.jpg" name="twitter" border=0 width=40 height=40>
            <img src="./images/linkedin.jpg" name="linkedin" border=0 width=40 height=40>
            <img src="./images/youtube.jpg" name="youtube" border=0 width=40 height=40>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Please suggest whats going wrong here...

Answer (score 5):

It is outdated.  Use style="vertical-align:top" instead.

Comment: All the images have the same dimension. Vertical-align:top aligns the cell content based on tallest sibling cell. In this case all of your cells have the same height so you may not see what you wanted to see.

Comment: While it may be recommended in some spec that CSS be used instead of presentational HTML attributes, such policies do not address the problem. The CSS code does just the same as the HTML code (except that the latter works even when CSS is disabled in the browser).

Answer (score 2):

I got my error. I was not closing img tag. When I closed every img tag, it worked :)

```
<table> 
   <tr>
      <td valign="top">                       
         <img src="./images/facebook.jpg" name="facebook" border=0 width=40 height=40 />
         <img src="./images/twitter.jpg" name="twitter" border=0 width=40 height=40 />
         <img src="./images/linkedin.jpg" name="linkedin" border=0 width=40 height=40 />
         <img src="./images/youtube.jpg" name="youtube" border=0 width=40 height=40 />
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That’s not possible. Adding the slash has no effect, except when the document is interpreted as genuinely XHTML, and then the code you initially posted would not show anything but a well-formedness error. What you have really done to remove the problem, which you did not actually describe, was something else.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you mean by “does not work”, but probably you mean that there is some empty space below the images in the cell even if you set padding in the cell to zero. The reason to this is that `img` elements are, by default, aligned to text baseline, as you can see by inspecting them in a browser’s development mode (the computed style shows `vertical-align: baseline`). A solution to this is to set their alignment in CSS:

```
img { vertical-align: top; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged the question with the [css](/questions/tagged/css) tag, so I guess CSS is ok for you.

You can try the following:

```
<td style="vertical-align: top;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table> 
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top">                       
      <img src="./images/facebook.jpg" name="facebook" style="border:0;width:40; height:40">
      <img src="./images/twitter.jpg" name="twitter" style="border:0;width:40; height:40">
      <img src="./images/linkedin.jpg" name="linkedin" style="border:0;width:40; height:40">
      <img src="./images/youtube.jpg" name="youtube" style="border:0;width:40; height:40">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```